# Populate OneToOneField after submitting form Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code which creates a new user and tries to create a profile for that user:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

@login_required(login_url="/login")
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            profile = Profile().save() 
            user = form
            user.profile = profile
            user.save()

            return redirect('users')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    user_model = get_user_model()
    users = user_model.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(users, 15) 

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    users = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, 'users/index.html', {'users': users, 'form': form})

class Profile(models.Model):
    has_premium_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    has_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    has_telegram_premium_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    has_telegram_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

When I'm submitting the form the user as well as the profile is created but the profile is not stored in the user (the profile_id stays null).

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Your `form` is *not* a user, it is simply the `ProfileForm` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` is actually just a reference to the `ProfileForm` you constructed. You can obtain the user that has logged in with `request.user`. So you can update the user with:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = Profile().save() 
            user = request.user
            user.profile = profile
            user.save()
            return redirect('users')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    # …
```